# How to define the result of a Task<int> test with Xunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

one of my first atempts of testing with XUnit.
I need to test this API:

```
[HttpPut("Update")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> UpdateWeatherForecast([FromBody] WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
    {
       var exist= await _euroNextService.UpdateAsync(weatherForecast.Date, weatherForecast);
        if (exist==0  )
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return NoContent();
    }
```

This the test I have so far:

```
 [Fact]
  public async Task TestUpdateReturnsNoResult()
  {
      // Arrange
      var euroNextServiceMock = new Mock<IEuronextService>();
      var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<WeatherForecastController>>();
 
      WeatherForecast forecast = new WeatherForecast() { Date = new DateOnly(2024, 3, 16), TemperatureC = 20 };
      DateOnly date = new DateOnly(2024, 3, 13);
    var tst=  euroNextServiceMock.Setup(r => r.UpdateAsync(date, forecast) ).ReturnsAsync(1); //here it returns 0

      // Act 
      var controller = new WeatherForecastController(loggerMock.Object, euroNextServiceMock.Object);
      var result = await controller.UpdateWeatherForecast(forecast);

      //Assert
      Assert.IsType<NoContentResult>(result.Result);
  }
```

with forecast defined as :

```
public class WeatherForecast
    {
        [Required, Key]
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    }
```

and ExecuteUpdateAsync:

```
      public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(DateOnly date, WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
       { 
         return await _appDbContext.WeatherForecasts.Where(x => x.Date == date).ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters=>setters
           .SetProperty(s=>s.TemperatureC, weatherForecast.TemperatureC));
       }
```

how can I have euroNextServiceMock returns 1 or any result but 0? It mocks the result of an ExecuteUpdateAsync and should return the rows updated.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling your `euroNextServiceMock` to return 1 if it is given the date 16th March 2024 and the `forecast` object.

During your test you then call your controller with the date of 13th March 2024 and the `forecast` object. The controller method then calls the `euroNextService` mock with these values.

Of course, the mock hasn't been told what value to return if it is given the date 13th March 2024 and `forecast`, so it returns 0, because that's the default `int` value.

Change both dates in your test to be the same, and you should find your test passes.

Comment: O h my, so obvious. Thank you it works.